# Generic UI template using Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Can you please guide me to generate generic UI template using Angular2? Here is my requirement.I would like to create generic UI template for the `Login` and `Logout` functionality.At this moment I have put same code base each and every page.Which is horrible.Please guide me to refactor this in a better way?

This is one of such component or page.

**event-schedule.html**

```
 <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="login()" *ngIf="token==null || token.length==0"><ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logout()" *ngIf="token!=null && token.length>0"><ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

**event-schedule.ts**

```
export class EventSchedulePage
{
 token: string = '';

 constructor(...) {
 }

     //to login
      login(): void {
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      }

      //to logout
      logout(): void {
        this.removeToken().then((val) => {
          this.token = val;
        });

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? elaborate it in your post

Comment: The problem is, let's say we have 10 pages on the app.Then I have to put `login` and `logout` button on each and every page or component.For that, I have to duplicate the same code base on each page.So I have decided to create generic UI component and use that component each and every page.Then I don't need to duplicate the same code no? Hope now it is clear? @Aravind

Comment: instead of doing like this you can have the component in the main layout page itself

Comment: Yes, How can I do that with Ionic2? Do you know about it? @Aravind

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are aware but ionic team has a starter project with many things(login, menu, map, etc.) already included. Maybe that can help you. Here is the link to the [repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super)

Comment: Thanks for the template.I normally use CLI tool only.Have you worked on this template?

Comment: Honestly I haven't used it for a project yet, just for code example.

Comment: hmm.. Me too try that later.Thanks for the info :)